# Strange string array declaration Syntax

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

```
private final String[] okFileExtensions = new String[] { "csv" };
```

Would someone please explain why `{}` is written after a String array declaration?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using an enumeration, instead of explicitly hardcoding the file extensions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's an array of one element. In this case containing the `String` `"csv"`.

When written as part of a declaration, this can be written in a more concise form:

```
private final String[] okFileExtensions = { "csv" };
```

Multiple-element arrays use commas between values. There needn't be any values at all.

```
private final String[] okFileExtensions = { "csv", "tsv" };

private final String[] noFileExtensions = { };
```

It may be worth noting that although the reference is final the array is not. So you can write:

```
    okFileExtensions[0] = "exe";
```

A way to get around this is to switch to collections and use an unmodifiable implementation:

```
private final Set<String> okFileExtensions = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
    new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList({
        "csv"
    }));
```

JDK8 is intended to have enhancement to collections that will make this more concise. Probably `List` and `Set` literals within the language. Possibly:

```
private final Set<String> okFileExtensions = { "csv" };
```

Collections should generally be preferred over arrays (for reference types).

Comment: If you wanted to add multiple file extension values to the array you would just separate them with commas eg. private final String[] okFileExtensions = { "csv", "txt", "sql" };

Comment: I have now added that to my answer.

Comment: `Collections should generally be preferred over arrays (for reference types)` that depends largely on what the purpose and scope of the array is. As given here this is much too general for my taste.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the JDK7 enhancement. Didn't knew that particular one. Looks very useful.

Answer (score 4):

That's the Java's valid syntax for array declaration.

You may use that when you are passing an array without declaring a variable:

```
 public void printArray( String [] someArray ) {
      for( String s : someArray) {
          System.out.println( s );
      }
  }
```

And invoke it like this:

```
  printArray( new String [] { "These", "are", "the", "contents"} );
```

The curly braces can only be used when declaring the array so the following is not allowed:

```
Stirng [] a;

a = {"on", "two"};
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating an array of `strings` inline.

Answer (score 1):

I think a less verbose (also confusing) declaration would have been :

```
private final String[] okFileExtensions = {"csv"};
```

Comment: Maybe ... but the `new <type>[] {...}` syntax can do more.